# Options and component trying to control descendant binding

Tags: knockout.js

In the fiddle below, I am trying to have one of several components rendered based on a field in the data being iterated. I have defined these templates:

```
<template id="select-template">
    <select data-bind="style: {width: size}, value: value, options: options, optionsText: 'optTxt', optionsValue: 'optId'"></select>
</template>
<template id="input-template">
    <!--input type="text" data-bind="style: {width: size}, value: value" /-->
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: 'input'" />
</template>
<template id="mu-template">
    <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
</template>
```

And registered these corresponding components:

```
ko.components.register('input', {
    viewModel: InputModel,
    template: {
        element: 'input-template'
    }
});
ko.components.register('select', {
    viewModel: InputModel,
    template: {
        element: 'select-template'
    }
});
ko.components.register('mu', {
    viewModel: InputModel,
    template: {
        element: 'mu-template'
    }
});
```

The viewmodel constructor they all use is:

```
function InputModel(params) {
    if (!('id' in params)) {
        throw "Model broke";
    }
    var keys = ['id', 'size', 'value', 'options'];
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; ++i) {
        var k = keys[i];
        if (k in params) {
            this[k] = params[k];
        }
    }
    console.debug("Model:", [this]);
}
```

I have two issues:

1. When the select template is being rendered, I get an error saying
   `Multiple bindings (options and component) are trying to control descendant bindings of the same element. You cannot use these bindings together on the same element.`
2. Probably related, if I don't do the error check/throw in `InputModel`, it gets called in an infinite loop with no parameters.

What is going on here?

http://jsfiddle.net/6srq9yfc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are registering your components with the names of existing DOM elements: `input`, `select`.

Because of this, KO tries to bind the

```
<select data-bind="style: {width: size}, 
            value: value, options: options, 
            optionsText: 'optTxt', optionsValue: 'optId'"></select>`
```

**as a component** which gets into a conflict into the `options` binding and you get the error message.

You can easily fix this with renaming your components to non existing DOM elements:

```
ko.components.register('my-input', {
    viewModel: InputModel,
    template: {
        element: 'input-template'
    }
});
ko.components.register('my-select', {
    viewModel: InputModel,
    template: {
        element: 'select-template'
    }
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bx101n9h/).